# Regex to match single character filenames with an extension

Tags: regex, boost, filenames

I'm needing to locate any file that contains a single character filename with a 1-3 character extension.

I've spent some time searching for how to do this, but can't see to find the right combination of regex.  I'm using a solution that requires boost regex, which I think is similar to perl regex.

Here are some examples should match:

```
1.exe
a.c
-.zip  (a hyphen is ok for the first part of the filename)
```

These examples should not match:

```
1 (doesn't have an extension)
1a.exe (has 2+ chars before the period)
```

Examples I've tried:

```
^[.]+\.[a-z0-9]{1,3}$
^[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]{1,3}$
^[\w]\.[\w]{1,3}$
^([0-9a-z]{1})\..{1,3}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

[`^[\w\-]\.\w{1,3}$`](https://regex101.com/r/Q4StSN/1/)

**Explanation**

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- Match a word character or a hyphen`^[\w\-]`
- Match a dot `\.`
- Match a word character between one and three times
- The end of the string `$`

Or more restricted instead of the `\w`:

[`^[a-zA-Z\d\-]\.[a-zA-Z]{1,3}$`](https://regex101.com/r/Q4StSN/3)

Comment: I think the more restricted one is actually the good one. `\w` matches any word character equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` so that would allow an underscore as the filename and/or in the extension.